# Proper form of the verb in "I didn’t realize I _____ (drive) fast."

Tags: tense

Could you please tell me the proper form of the word given in the bracket?

> — You are making me nervous. Would you slow down?
>
> — Oh! I’m sorry. I didn’t realize I _____ (drive) fast.

I think the correct answer is "was driving" / "had driven"

Comment: No, no, you go first. Give it a shot at spelling out what you imagine is the right answer.

Comment: @YosefBaskin was driving / had driven ...

Comment: You think *I driving fast* is good?

Comment: _I was driving fast_ during the drive. _I had driven fast_ after the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The verb should be “was driving.”  Past imperfect tense.